# is extra whitespace allowed in RSS feeds

Tags: xml, rss

For years I thought "extra" whitespace in an RSS feed is allowed. The feeds validate fine on W3C but one client is complaining about these whitespaces. I'll probably conform to their system for expediency, but I'm wondering who's in the right here.

Sample of my feed:

```
<channel>
<title><![CDATA[Title]]></title>
<description>![CDATA[Description]]></description>
```

The way they need it:

```
<channel><title><![CDATA[Title]]></title><description>![CDATA[Description]]></description>
```

is their system fragile or is my system wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

<s>It's not that anyone is wrong per se, but that they've violated the [robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) in writing their code too rigidly.</s>

**EDIT:**

I take this back. They're wrong as hell. XML allows that spacing, and since they don't accept it they don't accept XML, and hence RSS.

Comment: +1 for `They're wrong as hell.` My guess is that they're trying to do some sort of processing on the XML based on pattern matching/regular expressions. Why else would whitespace matter?

Answer (score 0):

I thought it did not matter either.

The spec seems to suggest that pretty printing is allowed.  Although it does state that all characters will be parsed.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-white-space

Which explains this... which says some parsers treat white space outside of elements differently.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx